# how to sync windows time from a ntp time server in command

Tags: windows, time, ntp

I am working on windows 7. I can sync time of win7 from a ntp linux server manually. How can I do that in command prompt. So I can run it on windows startup. And windows task plan not work for me. The time should be like this:

```
Linux server -->  windows 7.
```

Any one knows that? Thank you. I can read msdn.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use net time
`net time \\timesrv /set /yes`

after your comment try this one in evelated prompt :

```
w32tm /config /update /manualpeerlist:yourtimerserver
```

Comment: service not start @Kayasax  I have run sc start w32time. Windows time service already started.

Comment: It runs successfully without error. But time was not change. When I run `time /t`. It make me crazy. @Kayasax

Comment: Is there exists a delay? @Kayasax

Comment: It will not change other machine in local network and domain, right?

Comment: nope, except if you do that on your domain time server

Comment: My machine is client. Not domain server. and not time server.

Comment: Oh my god. It changes now. Thank you.

Comment: @Kayasax  `w32tm /resync` says "The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big." as my CMOS battery is dead and my computer clock resets on every boot at 1/1/2000 12:00 AM. Any help?

Comment: @Kayasax Found solution as per http://blog.bruteforcetech.com/archives/911 , do not forget to restart W32Time service `net stop W32Time` then retry `w32tm /resync`

Comment: Also if you are on a VM turn off the VMICTimeProvider with the following registry tweak!  https://serverfault.com/a/490619/169771

Answer (score 65):

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.it.pool.ntp.org 1.it.pool.ntp.org 2.it.pool.ntp.org 3.it.pool.ntp.org"
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

.BAT Sample File: https://gist.github.com/thedom85/dbeb58627adfb3d5c3af

I also recommend this program: http://www.timesynctool.com/

Comment: Solved my problem thanks. I have a workstation that is domain joined so time settings "Are managed by your organisation" but is is being used away from the domain at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

If you just need to `resync` windows time, open an **elevated command prompt** and type:

```
w32tm /resync
```

---

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /resync 
Sending resync command to local computer 
The command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 10):

While the `w32tm /resync` in theory does the job, it only does so under certain conditions. When "down to the millisecond" matters, however, I found that Windows wouldn't actually make the adjustment; as if "oh, I'm off by 2.5 seconds, close enough bro, nothing to see or do here".

In order to truly force the resync (Windows 7):

1. Control Panel -> Date and Time
2. "Change date and time..." (requires Admin privileges)
3. Add or Subtract a few minutes (I used -5 minutes)
4. Run "cmd.exe" as administrator
5. `w32tm /resync`
6. Visually check that the seconds in the "Date and Time" control panel are ticking at the same time as your authoritative clock(s). (I used `watch -n 0.1 date` on a Linux machine on the network that I had SSH'd over into)

--- Rapid Method ---

1. Run "cmd.exe" as administrator
2. `net start w32time` (Time Service must be running)
3. `time 8` (where 8 may be replaced by any 'hour' value, presumably 0-23)
4. `w32tm /resync`
5. Jump to 3, as needed.