# How to configure windows to continuously sync time with a known ip using powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, time, synchronization

Every time I add a computer to my network I run a script to set everything up as needed. One of the actions I need to perform is making the new computer's clock synchronize with a certain computer on the network (i.e. ip x.x.x.x).

I know I could make it sync once using:

```
NET TIME \\x.x.x.x /SET /Y
```

But I want the computers to stay synced with x.x.x.x (as would happen with an internet server if I manually chose "synchronize with an internet time server" in "internet time settings").

Is there a Powershell command that will change Windows' settings so it will keep sync with x.x.x.x?
(I know I can write a script to run the above command e.g. every day and make it run on startup on each of the machines on the network, but I prefer adding a line (or a couple) to the script I run once when setting up a new machine)

Thank you!

Comment: What is enforcing the time server now? Group Policy? It sounds like something is doing it.

Comment: Duplicate? It's not technically powershell, but you can certainly run these commands from a powershell script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862236/how-to-sync-windows-time-from-a-ntp-time-server-in-command

Comment: Matt, currently we update the time manually every once in a while using the command in the OP.
BrettGreen, I'll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the Windows time service (`w32time`) with the `w32tm` tool to sync from another machine (via NTP) in PowerShell like this:

```bsh
Start-Process w32tm -ArgumentList "/config /update /manualpeerlist:x.x.x.x /syncfromflags:MANUAL"
```

Where:

- `x.x.x.x` is your IP address
- `/config` to configure `w32time` service
- `/update` to apply the new config immediately
- `/manualpeerlist:` to define the source where to sync from
- `/syncfromflags:MANUAL` to make sure that no other sources than the manually defined peer list are used

Comment: Thanks for resolve my WMI problem `Get-WmiObject : A security package specific error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070721)`.